# Knowing renderer which I click it

Tags: vtk

I have a render window where I spread 4 renderers ... how can I know on which of them I made click ? I have seen some examples of how to know the object on I made click, not renderer ...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to get the clicked renderer through the interactor of the renderwindow.

e.g.

```
int x = myRenderWindow->GetInteractor()->GetEventPosition()[0];
int y = myRenderWindow->GetInteractor()->GetEventPosition()[1];
vtkRenderer myPokedRenderer = myRenderWindow->GetInteractor()->FindPokedRenderer(x, y);
```

Comment: Johnny, what is happen when myRenderWindow are not spread on entire screen ? Seem not find the correct renderer ... see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28580353/convert-mouse-position