# Convert mouse position

Tags: 3d, vtk

I have following code:

```
int p[2];
m_pRenderWindow->GetInteractor()->GetEventPosition(p);
vtkRenderer* pFoundRenderer = m_pRenderWindow->GetInteractor()->FindPokedRenderer(p[0], p[1]);

if(m_pRenderer2 == pFoundRenderer)
{
    // do something
}
```

On the m_*pRenderWindow* I have 4 renderers ... when the m_*pRenderWindow* is restored, (**is not spread on entire screen for instance**), *p[0]* and *p[1]* are NOT correct ( when the mouse is over a renderer3 the code says that the mouse is over renderer2, or something) ... why ?

I guess that mouse coordinates should be converted into client coordinates ... but how ?

Comment: When do you capture the coordinates? Do you created an event handler for your interactor?

Comment: Yes, I derived a class from vtkCommand, named vtkImageInteractionCallback, but there I only send a message to render window, just like that: case vtkCommand::MouseWheelForwardEvent: ::PostMessage(m_pView->m_hWnd, WMU_VTKMOUSEWHEEL, 1, 0);

Comment: In m_pView I have code from above ...

Comment: Never tried the callback function, i have worked with the interactorstyle and this is working pretty good with picking the renderer e.g. [http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Interaction/MouseEvents](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Interaction/MouseEvents)